# p:commandButton action method invoked multiple times on single click

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am using JSF 2.2/PrimeFaces 5.1. I've a command button which performs a search and adds a faces message.

XHTML:

```
<p:commandButton id="search" value="Search" 
    update="emptyId,empAtendanceTable,msgDialog" 
    action="#{attendanceBean.buttonAction(actionEvent)}" />
```

Bean:

```
public void buttonAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    if (fromDate.after(todate)) {
        addMessage("To date cannot be after from date");
    }
}
```

However, when I click the button, the action method is invoked multiple times and causes the message being added multiple times.

[image]

How is this caused and how can I solve it? The action method needs to be invoked only once.

Comment: A http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would be helpful. My guess would be that there's something fishy going on in the component tree. E.g. using `binding` on a too broad bean and/or programmatically instead of declaratively building components.

Comment: Thanks for the link.From next time onwards i follow the link for questions.In my case in p:commandbutton if i give action event in bean for validation it fires only modal with message but data-table not rendering.Other-case if i change to normal String function in button event then it shows data-table but not modal message .How to solve this issue.For this multiple time message gave a message in getter thats the problem.I removed its shows one time message.

Comment: Eh? The dialog is not the problem here. The action method being invoked multiple times is the problem here. You need to fix that problem of the action method being invoked multiple times. Then the (side) effects of that problem will disappear all by itself. Again, please provide a MCVE.

Comment: Thanks .Now action method is called only once,But if only validation message is coming data table not showing the records.

Comment: That's a different problem. Coming back to the action method problem where this question was all about, did you say that you already solved it? Then you should post an answer for that. For that new problem, just ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Now modal dialog display a message only once.The problem is i put the validation in getter .I removed in getter its working fine .